# Losing line-feeds/carriage-returns on post

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Any help on how I would keep carriage-returns in the text that I am posting?

```
 
function checkPlayState(checkStatus) {
    var Player = document.getElementById("NSPlay");
    if (Player.playState == 0 || Player.playState == 1) {  // 0 vs 8
        if (checkStatus == true) {


            var tex_t = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextArea1").innerHTML; 


        // The following javascript function takes the URL of the target page and 
        // a name / value paire and POSTs the data to the supplied URL by dynamically
        // creating a form and then submitting it...
        // but I am loosing line-feeds/carage-returns in the transfer of the text

      var fil_e = "Speach.aspx" // target url

 post_to(fil_e, tex_t); 

  function post_to (file, text) {
         var myForm = document.createElement("form");
         myForm.action = file;
         myForm.method = "post";


    var myInput = document.createElement("input");
    myInput.setAttribute("name", "key");
    myInput.setAttribute("value", tex_t); // squares show in the "Text Visualizer" when yellow is here
    myForm.appendChild(myInput); // squares have gone in the "Text Visualizer" when we are here but show in the value field of watch window???

  document.body.appendChild(myForm);
  myForm.submit();     
  document.body.removeChild(myForm);
 }

            return;

        } else {

            window.setTimeout("checkPlayState(true)", 500);
        }

    } else {

        window.setTimeout("checkPlayState(false)", 500);

    }
}

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' I have this in aspx file to retrieve ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


            Dim tex_t As Object
            tex_t = Request.Form("key")
            If tex_t  "" Then  ' Here while debugging the squares are gone?!?

                TextArea1.InnerText = tex_t  ' it is the same textarea too

            Else

            End If
```

Answer (score 1):

use URL encoding.  a new line is represented as `%0A`

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm says you can use the javascript function `escape`

```
function checkPlayState(checkStatus) {
    var Player = document.getElementById("NSPlay");
    if (Player.playState == 0 || Player.playState == 1) {  // 0 vs 8
        if (checkStatus == true) {


            var tex_t = escape(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextArea1").innerHTML); 

        // The following javascript function takes the URL of the target page and 
        // a name / value paire and POSTs the data to the supplied URL by dynamically
        // creating a form and then submitting it...
        // but I am loosing line-feeds/carage-returns in the transfer of the text

      var fil_e = "Speach.aspx" // target url

 post_to(fil_e, tex_t); 

  function post_to (file, text) {
         var myForm = document.createElement("form");
         myForm.action = file;
         myForm.method = "post";


    var myInput = document.createElement("input");
    myInput.setAttribute("name", "key");
    myInput.setAttribute("value", tex_t); // squares show in the "Text Visualizer" when yellow is here
    myForm.appendChild(myInput); // squares have gone in the "Text Visualizer" when we are here but show in the value field of watch window???

  document.body.appendChild(myForm);
  myForm.submit();     
  document.body.removeChild(myForm);
 }

            return;

        } else {

            window.setTimeout("checkPlayState(true)", 500);
        }

    } else {

        window.setTimeout("checkPlayState(false)", 500);

    }
}
```

Then for your aspx file use:

```
Dim tex_t As Object
tex_t = Request.Form("key")
If tex_t  "" Then  ' Here while debugging the squares are gone?!?

    TextArea1.InnerText = Server.UrlDecode(tex_t)  ' it is the same textarea too

Else

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i  -1) {
                    //
                 tex_t = tex_t.replace("something", %0A );
               } 
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

UrlDecode did the trick Chris... Sorry too, I can't see an "add comment link" anywhere.

Comment: Just found this bloody thing - as said am a nobb - now all I have do do is find the checkbox... will keep at it. Thanks again Chris ;)